# How to config Prometheus to scrape all IPs behind a hostname in single period?

Tags: prometheus

I have configured all my servers behind a hostname and I want to scrape metrics from all the servers in one period.

When I config as following:

```yaml
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: gamelet-smoba
    honor_timestamps: true
    metrics_path: /metrics
    scheme: http
    relabel_configs:
        - source_labels: [__meta_dns_name]
          target_label: service
    dns_sd_configs:
        - names:
            - my-hostname
          refresh_interval: 2s
          type: A
          port: 29836
```

The prometheus draw like:

[image]

Which means the `dns_sd_configs` can be alternative of a single IP?

What should I do if I want to monitor all the IPs?

Comment: Does your DNS record return all IPs or just one in round-robin fashion? Compare with this `dig +short google.com`.

Comment: @anemyte no, just return single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration in the question appears correct for the task. However, in order to make it work, the DNS response must contain ***all target IPs at once***. The way it works is like this:

1. Prometheus makes a DNS request to obtain a list of targets.
2. The list of targets gets cached for `refresh_interval: 2s`.
3. Prometheus makes a scrape request for each target in the list.

At next iterations (defined by the `scrape_interval`) Prometheus may skip p.1 and p.2 if the the list of targets is not yet expired. The problem in the question is that DNS server returned only one IP and thus, Prometheus at each  `scrape_interval` made only one scrape request. The randomly selected target received it's unique IP-based `instance` label and this is why the graph looks disconnected.